# How to access the uniqueID property from an HtmlElement?

Tags: c#, winforms, mshtml

How can I access the [uniqueID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property from an [HtmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx)?

I know how to cast from `HtmlElement` to MSHTML's interfaces, but I don't know which interface to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
mshtml.IHTMLUniqueName id = element.DomElement as mshtml.IHTMLUniqueName;
MessageBox.Show(id.uniqueID);
```

Comment: How do you get DomElement from IHTMLElement ?

Comment: `IHTMLElement` is already the DomElement. In my example `element` is an `HtmlElement` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but "element as mshtml.IHTMLUniqueName;" returns just the HTMLElement not IHTMLUniqueName

Comment: What is your `element`? Is it an `IHTMLElement` or an `HtmlElement`?

Comment: IHTMLElement, do you mean HTMLHtmlElement ? HTMLElement does not exists inside mshtml

Comment: There is [IHTMLElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(v=vs.85).aspx) and [HtmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx). In my example, `element` is an instance of `HtmlElement`. And the `DomElement` property gives you the underlying COM object which can be cast to several interfaces such as `IHTMLElement` or `IHTMLUniqueName`.